# Files in my DocumentRoot directory are not being served when I enter their URLs in my web browser

Tags: linux, apache

I have installed Apache 2.4.9 on my linux machine.  I am trying to set up a local website for a school project and I have added the following to httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/home/jared/classes/cs275-spring/final_project"
```

I have verified that the Directory supplied to DocumentRoot is valid.  Under this directory, there is a file called hello.html.  When I try to access the file by going to localhost/hello.html, I am greeted with a 404 page.  However, just going to "localhost" seems to work fine.  Any ideas as to what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following config after restarting your HTTPD server:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /home/jared/classes/cs275-spring/final_project
</VirtualHost>
```